# Loading dataGridView XML adds new columns to grid

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a dataGridView that I have created through Visual Studio.

[image]

I then have a save method which copies the table to a DataSet and then saves it to XML:

```
if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("whereClause");
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                DataColumn column = new DataColumn(dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].Name);

                dt.Columns.Add(column);
            }
            int ColumnCount = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
                {
                    dataRow[i] = dr.Cells[i].Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }

            XmlTextWriter newXml = new XmlTextWriter(savefile.FileName, Encoding.UTF8);
            ds.WriteXml(newXml);
            newXml.Close();
        }
```

I then have a matching load method:

```
 if (openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            //Create xml reader
            XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(openfile.FileName, new XmlReaderSettings());
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            //Read xml to dataset
            dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["whereClause"];

            //Close xml reader
            xmlFile.Close();

        }
```

My issue is that when this data is loaded back in, it creates new columns to the side of the table, and does not load it the data to my existing table structure. I looked into DataSet.Merge but struggled to get this to function as required. How can I load the XML back in and map it to the existing columns in the table structure? The whole table can be cleared when its loaded if necessary.

Comment: Hold on when you are rebinding the dataGridView1 set its datasource to be null, call DataBind() then set the DataSource to be dataSet.Tables["whereClause"]?

Answer (score 1):

Set the property on the DataGridView AutoGenerateColumns to be false.

You would however need to set the field which each column is binded to manually. For example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Forename" HeaderText="Column 1" /> <!-- state each column -->
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind example:

```
        List<Customer> cu = new List<Customer>();
        cu.Add(new Customer() {  Forename = "Onam" });
        gridView1.DataSource = cu;
        gridView1.DataBind();

public class Customer
{
    public string Forename { get; set; }
}
```

Or you could simply do the following (with setting AutoGenerateColumns = true):

```
gridView1.DataSource = null;
gridView1.DataBind();
gridView1.Columns.Clear();
gridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["whereClause"];
gridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Each column you have in your DataGrid have it mapped to a field in your XML. I have edited above giving example :)